# how to get value from selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

sir, i have a form input like input text and radio button.
how to get the value of selected radio button, and put that value to the input type text.

heres jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/czw71dfk/2/

```
    <div id="gender" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">I Sign up as</label>
    <input #id="place" type="text" class="form-control" readonly/>
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <label class="label_item" for="radioMale">
        <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="male"  name="gender" id="radioMale">
      </label>
      <p class="text-center colorGrey">Male</p>
     </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <label class="label_item" for="radioFemale">
        <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="female"  name="gender" id="radioFemale">
      </label>
      <p class="text-center colorGrey">Female</p>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <label class="label_item" for="radioKids">
        <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Kids" name="gender" id="radioKids">
      </label>
      <p class="text-center colorGrey">Kids</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('#gender input').on('change', function() {
    var gender = $( this ).val();
   $("#place").val( gender );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML problem `#id="place"`,

And must be using on change;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[name=gender]').on('change', function() {
    var gender = $( this ).val();
     $("#place").val( gender );
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle.net Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cvoun5et/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `#id="place"` To `id="place"` https://jsfiddle.net/czw71dfk/4/

```
<input #id="place" type="text" class="form-control" readonly/>
```

To

```
<input id="place" type="text" class="form-control" readonly/>
```